# Keyboard shortcut to make a selection from a dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working in Google Sheets and I've set up validation lists in a column.  When I tab into that column the dropdown handle appears:

[image: Selected cell with drop-down list handle]

In order to access values from the list, I have to move my hand from the keyboard to the mouse and then use the mouse to select the appropriate value.

I looked at [the spreadsheet docs](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1360901&parent=1360868&ctx=topic), but the only thing I saw in there was how to create these cells.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to make a selection from the dropdown?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new version of Google Sheets makes it very simple.

1. Navigate to the cell containing the dropdown.
2. Open the dropdown using one of the following keys:
   <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>
3. Navigate within the list using the up <kbd>↑</kbd> and down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows.
4. If you type any characters, the list will automatically filter to display only those items that begin with the same characters.  For example, filtering by typing "**y**" returns "**y**es" and "**y**ellow" but not "bab**y**".
5. Save your selection using one of the following keys:
   <kbd>ENTER</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Just accidently ran into the solution. I hit F2 while I was on a drop down and it opened the drop down and I was able to scroll through my drop down and select the specific drop down item that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

In Google sheet
F2 is actually more suitable to open the drop-down menu.

However, If you are aware of the list contents then go to the dropdown cell and simply type the first letter of the value that you wanted to select, you will be able to see all the values that start with the letter you type and then you can simply select the values by UP OR DOWN Arrows.

Plus it will filter the values and will make the menu list shorter if the menu list is too long.

Comment: You can improve your answer by explaining *why* you believe `F2`is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

In Google sheets, when the cell with a validation is the active cell hit the space bar and your list will appear. Use the arrow keys for up and down, hit return on the entry needed or hit escape to move on.