# In Google Sheets is there a key or hotkey that can complete an entry from a drop down cell?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm making entries on a daily basis and one of the cells I'm filling in is drop down with 20+ options. For ease I can start type the option I need and I wondered is there a hot key to complete the one that I'm typing?

I have looked at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30247/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-drop-down-list-for-cell-values-in-google-docs-spread but that does not help. While typing if I press enter it just creates a new one. Let's say I need "accommodation". I can start typing "acc" and see it, what hotkey is going to complete the rest? Tried with tab, space, ctrl, enter... they didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut to open a drop-down list for cell values in Google Docs spreadsheets](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30247/keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-drop-down-list-for-cell-values-in-google-docs-spread)

Comment: that does not help, while typing if I press enter it just create a new one. Let's say i need "accommodation", I can start typing "acc" and see it, what hotkey is going to complete the rest. Tried with tab, space, ctrl, enter... they didn't work

Comment: Press Down/Up until the desired option is highlighted, then press Enter.

Comment: @pnuts Another reason we need to encourage people not to leave important information in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Google Sheets is there a key or hotkey that can complete an entry from a drop down cell?

No.

Available hotkeys are shown [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).